# How to call a random function in lua?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

What should I do if i want to call a random function when an if statement is true?

```
local function move() end
local function move2() end
local function move3() end

if (statement) then
//make it choose a random function from the three which are above
end
```

Comment: `local next_move = ({move, move2, move3})[math.random(3)]; next_move()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have You considered putting those function in the table and picking random index for a function to be executed? For example something like following:

```
local math = require("math")

function a()
    print("a")
end

function b()
    print("b")
end

function c()
    print("c")
end

function execute_random(f_tbl)
    local random_index = math.random(1, #f_tbl) --pick random index from 1 to #f_tbl
    f_tbl[random_index]() --execute function at the random_index we've picked
end

-- prepare/fill our function table
local funcs = {a, b, c}

-- seed the pseudo-random generator and try executing random function
-- couple of tens of times
math.randomseed(os.time())
for i = 0, 20 do
    execute_random(funcs)
end
```

Comment: This code will error. You make a call to `f_tbl` before you define it as a local. Lua will not use local variables outside of a block if defined after the function.

Comment: @ATaco the `f_tbl` is passed as an argument for the `execute_random()`, so, it does not have anything to do with local/global scoping. For the sanity and readability I'll rename it ;)